# Application no esta declarado Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Como puedo solucionar este error? lo que quiero hacer es obtener el valor de una ruta y almacenarla en mi variable, en este caso la variable carpeta tiene que obtener la ruta con "Application.StartupPath & "\imagenestemp" "

```
Public Function comprobartamano(ByVal imagenenbytes As Byte()) As String
        Dim nombre As String = numAleatorios(1, 10000000) & ".png"

        Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(imagenenbytes)
        Dim jpgoriginal As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        Dim jpg As Image

        Try
            Dim carpeta As String = Application.StartupPath & "\imagenestemp"

            Dim w As Int64 = jpgoriginal.Width
            Dim h As Int64 = jpgoriginal.Height
            Dim tamañoDeLaImagen As Int64
            Dim ruta As String
            ' Empezamos dividiendo por uno:
            For div As Int64 = 1 To 100
                ruta = System.IO.Path.Combine(carpeta, nombre)
                Dim porcentaje As Double = (100 - div) / 100
                Dim tp As Bitmap = Reduce(jpgoriginal, w * porcentaje, h * porcentaje)
                jpg = tp
                jpg.Save(ruta, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
                Dim fi As New FileInfo(ruta)
                tamañoDeLaImagen = fi.Length
                If tamañoDeLaImagen < 10 ^ 6 Then
                    Exit For ' si la imagen ocupa menos de 1 MByte -> fin del bucle
                End If
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(ruta)
                nombre = numAleatorios(1, 10000000) & ".png"

            Next

            Return ruta

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Function
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Answer (score 0):

En una aplicación de cónsola el objeto Application no está presente. Para conocer la carpeta que contiene el ejecutable puedes probar con lo siguiente:

```
    Dim rutaCompletaDelEjecutable As String =
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
    Dim carpetaDelEjecutable As String =
        System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(rutaCompletaDelEjecutable)
```

Comment: Lo voy a intentar y despues te digo, gracias de momento